# I ordered some expensive food and realised it was haram when it got here

Tags: sin

Im stressing out a lot because my parents will be mad as i still let them eat it without saying a word because i was scared. Also i cant say throw it away as it was 30 pounds worth. Will i be forgiven?

Answer (score 0):

What are you saying your food contains Haram material and will you eat that? Haram is Haram. You know it contains Haram just throw it away. You are thinking about your money? None of your worship will be accepted if you eat Haram food. You must eat food which is halal in Islam.
Jazakallah Khairan